# Oauth web service call for visual force apex program

Tags: web-services, oauth, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to get access to salesforce visual force page(no controller)   using oauth token.  I used the oauth token as session id and it is working fine, when i try to get access to other visual force page ( with controller)   it is directing me to salesforce login page asking to enter username/pwd to get requested page.